# How to do multiple queries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do a multiple queries. Here is my data frame:

```
data = {'Name':['Penny','Ben','Benny','Mark','Ben1','Ben2','Ben3'], 
        'Eng':[5,1,4,3,1,2,3], 
        'Math':[1,5,3,2,2,2,3],
        'Physics':[2,5,3,1,1,2,3],
        'Sports':[4,5,2,3,1,2,3],
        'Total':[12,16,12,9,5,8,12],
        'Group':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B']}

df1=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name','Eng','Math','Physics','Sports','Total','Group']) 
df1
```

[image]

I have 3 queries:

1. Group A or B
2. Math > Eng
3. Name starts with 'B'

I tried to do it one by one

```
df1[df1.Name.str.startswith('B')]
df1.query('Math > Eng')
df1[df1.Group == 'A'] #I cannot run the code with df1[df1.Group == 'A' or 'B']
```

Then, I tried to merge those queries

```
df1.query("'Math > Eng' & 'df1[df1.Name.str.startswith('B')]' & 'df1[df1.Group == 'A']")
TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (2, 0))
```

I also tried to pass `str.startswith()` into `df.query()`

```
df1.query("df1.Name.str.startswith('B')")
UndefinedVariableError: name 'df1' is not defined
```

I have tried lots of ways but no one works. How can I put those queries together?

Comment: Thanks for providing your data in a clean and easy way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The long way to solve this – and the one with the most transparency, so best for beginners – is to create a boolean column for each filter. Then sum those columns as one final filter:

```
df1['filter_1'] = df1['Group'].isin(['A','B'])
df1['filter_2'] = df1['Math'] > df1['Eng']
df1['filter_3'] = df1['Name'].str.startswith('B')

# If all are true
df1['filter_final'] = df1[['filter_1', 'filter_2', 'filter_3']].all(axis=1)
```

You can certainly combine these steps into one:

```
mask = ((df1['Group'].isin(['A','B'])) &
        (df1['Math'] > df1['Eng']) &
        (df1['Name'].str.startswith('B'))
       )

df['filter_final'] = mask
```

Lastly, selecting rows which satisfy your filter is done as follows:

```
df_filtered = df1[df1['filter_final']]
```

*This selects rows from `df1` where `final_filter == True`*

Comment: I'd be surprised if your second solution works. Maybe you need to replace `and` with `&`.

Comment: Correct. Fixed @QuangHoang -- thanks for the pointer

Comment: @YaakovBressler First, thank you so much, your explanation is very clear. However, what can I do if I want to present the answer in a table like `Ben : 1,5,5,1,6,A`? As the result is a Boolean. Thanks again.

Comment: Editing the answer to include @aukk123

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the answer is:

```
df1.query("Math > Eng & Name.str.startswith('B') & Group=='A'")
```

Additional comments

1. In `query`, the column's name doesn't accompany the data frame's name.
2. `df1[df1.Group.isin(['A', 'B'])]` or `df1.query("Group in ['A', 'B']")` instead of `df1[df1.Group == 'A' or 'B']`